# scrot command overwrites screenshot

Tags: lxde, screenshot

I am using LXDE and created a <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> hotkey that uses `scrot` to create a screenshot, but it's overwriting the file, again and again. I want it to create a new file every time I hit <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>. However, when I am pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd> to select the area to capture, it's creating a new file every time I am using it.

The command I used to create the hotkey is:

```
scrot '%Y-%m-%d_$wx$h_scrot.png' -e 'mv $f ~/Pictures/'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two simple options you can try:

1. increase the time resolution so that files created at least 1s apart have distinct names:

   ```
   scrot '%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S_$wx$h_scrot.png' -e 'mv $f ~/Pictures/'
   ```
2. add a `--backup=numbered` option to the `mv` command:

   ```
   scrot '%Y-%m-%d_$wx$h_scrot.png' -e 'mv --backup=numbered $f ~/Pictures/'
   ```

Comment: Thanks Tried First solution and it worked!! Mad respect <3